# QNetworkConfiguration and QNetworkConfigurationManager alternatives for Qt 5.15.2

Tags: qt

I am using Qt 5.15.2 enterprise edition on Windows 10. I am getting following warning messages continuously, though the application is working fine:

```
warning C4996: 'QNetworkConfiguration': was declared deprecated
```

While going through the documents, I realized that both QNetworkConfiguration and QNetworkConfigurationManager classes are obsolete, with a remark that these classes should not be used for new coding.

Please let me know what are the alternative classes to be used for the above two classes.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

if you follow comments on https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-58946
there's the info that Qt 6.1 supports the reachability in https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qnetworkinformation.html