# 3rd party library for Qt QNetworkConfiguration and QNetworkConfigurationManager classes

Tags: network-programming, qt5

Our dev environment:

OS: Windows 10 and Mac OS latest
Qt: 5.15.2

QNetworkConfiguatoin and QNetworkConfiguratoinManager, these classes are obsolete in Qt 5.15.2. Last week I had posted a query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65607210/qnetworkconfiguration-and-qnetworkconfigurationmanager-alternatives-for-qt-5-15). 
Is there any 3rd party C++ library which provides the same functionalities? As our application is for both Mac and Windows, it will be good to have a library supported for both the platform.